# Swift: Cell or Label be a http link in a UIcollectionView

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on an app that will utilize the UICollectionView to display content. I want to have either the cell or label be a link (http) that would be opened in safari.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {

var tableData: [String] = ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"]
var tableImages: [String] = ["img1.png", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"]






override func viewDidLoad() {




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: colvwCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colvwCell

    cell.lblCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages [indexPath.row])
    return cell

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use UITextView with attributed string:

swift 2.1

```
var str = "Google"
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:str, attributes:[NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!])

yourTextView.attributedText = attributedString
```

u can try this library for UILabel: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedStringAdditions/wiki/link-in-UILabel

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use UITextView to show and handle tap the link.
Code should be the following

```
@IBOutlet private weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()]

     let text = NSMutableAttributedString()
     text.beginEditing()
     text.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "google", attributes: [NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!]))
     text.endEditing()

     textView.attributedText = text
}
```

also it's required to set UITextView delegate inside the IB and implement this func

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

and do not forget to enable links detection in the IB
[image]